# Make child element height/width match parent exactly

Tags: html, css, size

I have a scenario where I have gray squares that I'd like to be covered *exactly* by orange squares.

[image: 3 gray boxes with orange boxes overlapping]

I have their respective heights/widths set exactly the same, but yet the browser renders the orange boxes so they're a *liiiiittle too tall*(1px) and a little too narrow(1px). Unfortunately, I can't just `calc(19vh - 1px)` to solve this because it depends on the viewport size. Where is this extra pixel coming from?

I've made a simplified example and posted it here: http://jsfiddle.net/165jnswd/

**Edit:**
An *even more* simplified example can be found here: http://jsfiddle.net/165jnswd/2/

Answer (score 0):

It's from the border-spacing of the table. If you set it to `0` the height of the table\tbody\tr\td is the same.

```css
table {
    table-layout: fixed;
    margin: 9vh auto 0;
    /*border-spacing: 0.6vh; -- change this -- */
    border-spacing: 0;
    border-collapse: separate;
  }

  td.cell {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1vh solid #999;
    border-radius: 1vh;
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #999;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    transition: background-color 0.25s ease;
  }

  .sz3x3 {
    width: 19vh;
    height: 19vh;
  }

  .sz4x4 {
    width: 14vh;
    height: 14vh;
  }

  td.black {
    background-color:#999;
    color:#fff;
  }

  td.white {
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #999;
  }

  td.par {
    background-color: #ffdfbd;
  }

  td.par.selected {
    background-color: #fdc07d;
  }

  td.selected {
    background-color: #eee;
  }

  .number {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 7.5vh;
  }

  #selector {
    top: -1vh;
    left: -0.9vh;
    border: 1vh solid #ef8d22;
    border-radius: 1vh;
    position: absolute;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    z-index: 999999;
  }
```

```html
<div id="game-content">
   <div id="game-screen"></div>
   <div id="board-container">
      <table>
         <tr>
            <td class="cell sz3x3" data-x="0" data-y="1">
               <div class="number"></div>
               <div id="selector" class="sz3x3"></div>
            </td>
            <td class="cell sz3x3" data-x="1" data-y="1">
               <div class="number"></div>
               <div id="selector" class="sz3x3"></div>
            </td>
            <td class="cell sz3x3" data-x="2" data-y="1">
               <div class="number"></div>
               <div id="selector" class="sz3x3"></div>
            </td>
         </tr>
      </table>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: When I run the code snippet on Chrome(on full screen) I still see the gray peeking out from behind the boxes. It's easier to see when you make the boxes massive, like if you change 19vh to 50vh

Comment: Do you mean the gray of the border?

Comment: Yup, the border of the box beneath the orange one shouldn't show through at all. I've modified my example to be even more simple and use px for positions/sizes, I'll update the question now to add it

Comment: I changed the width and the height of the `#selector` to 100%. Here: http://jsfiddle.net/4q0kb1c3/1/